# escape method is not supported by view page in admin area or backend of site in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, escaping, admin

I am new with zend framework. I am working in backend(the admin area of website) and want ot use escape but my view page is not supporting this. when I use escape method in view page, view page does not show anything. For this what I can do so I can use escape method in view page in admin area. Here is my code in controller:-

```
$this->view->assign('username', 'Username');    
$this->view->assign('password', 'Password');
$this->view->assign('rememberMe', 'Remember Me');
```

I am using this assign variable in view page like this:-

```
<td id="userlogin" align="left" width="30%"><?php echo escape($this->username);?>:</td>
```

But escape method is not supported by my view page in admin area. Please suggest me a trick for this...

Comment: one hint. In common usage `$this->view->assign('username', 'Username');` would by most people be used as `$this->view->username = 'Username';`. your way is correct and I'm sure works well, it's just not common to see. At least I rarely see it. Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean

```
<?php echo $this->escape($this->username);?>
```

escape is a function of the `Zend_View` class (`$this` in the context of templates) rather than a global PHP function.