# Fatal error: Call to undefined function escape() in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [escape method is not supported by view page in admin area or backend of site in zend framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135434/escape-method-is-not-supported-by-view-page-in-admin-area-or-backend-of-site-in)

I have installed zend framework properly on my localhost and got the zend framework default index page. Now I am using escape method in view page and run the page then it shows following error:-

Fatal error: Call to undefined function escape().....

I am not getting the solution to remove this error, I have set the virtual host and create site structure using Zend_Tool command like- zf create project myproject.

A directory structure I have got in proper way and when I run my site on localhost, it shows a zend default index page. So I assume that zend has installed properly on my system. A directory structure created by zend_tool have a blank library folder and there is no bin folder is showing in created directory structure of myproject folder.

I am using latest version of zend framework 1.11.11

I am very confused that why escape() method is not working

I am using following code in controller:-

```
$this->view->assign('username', 'Username');    
$this->view->assign('password', 'Password');
$this->view->assign('rememberMe', 'Remember Me');
```

I am calling escape method in view page as following:-

```
<td id="userlogin" align="left" width="30%"><?php echo escape($this->username);?>:</td>
```

In my controller I am not including any file. It is just a simple controller file like this:-

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
      /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
     // action body
    $request = $this->getRequest();  
    $this->view->assign('username', 'Username');    
    $this->view->assign('password', 'Password');
    $this->view->assign('rememberMe', 'Remember Me');
    }


}
```

Where I have made error please let me know.

Comment: You asked the exact same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11135434/212940) and received answers for it, why ask again?

Answer (score 1):

`escape()` is not a php function.

If you want to use ZF's view helper Zend_View_Helper_Escape, you need to call it on the view object:

`<?php echo $this->escape($this->username);?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try `$this->escape($this->username);` instead of just `escape($this->username);`

Comment: Because I don't think PHP has a function called 'escape'. And if he as a user defined function called 'escape' then Zend View already has a Helper to escape strings

Comment: Yes, exactly :) so why don't you say so in the answer?